# Are component of vectors vector and can we divide them into components?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, vectors

We know that two vectors can sum up and make one vector. And dividing a vector into components is the opposite process of summing vectors. Then the components of vectors should also be vectors. Are they really vectors? If they aren't, why are they scalar?

And if they are vectors, can we divide these components into more components?

Answer (score 2):

> And dividing a vector into components is the opposite process of summing two vectors.

It's not the "opposite process" because, given two vectors, there is only one sum; but given one vector, there are infinitely many pairs of vectors that sum to the given.

When you [decompose a vector into components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Decomposition), you do so with reference to a [set of basis vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), and the components are [scalars, by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)).

[Adding vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction), on the other hand, is a "pure" operation that can be defined without talking about components or any coordinate system.

Comment: In Cartesian coordinate system when we calculate cross or dot product of vectors then we dot /cross multiply the unit vectors. These unit vectors are components of the main vectors. Then how can we dot/cross multiply these components if they are not vectors?

Comment: The basis vectors of a coordinate system and the components that represent a vector in that system are not the same thing.  A 3D vector can be represented by $a_1\hat{i}+a_2\hat{j}+a_3\hat{k}$ where the $a_n$ are the three coordinates, and the $\hat{i}$,$\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$, are the three basis vectors.  If we say it's a _Cartesian_ coordinate system, we are saying that $\hat{i}$,$\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$ are all _unit vectors_ (i.e., $|\hat{i}|=1$, $|\hat{j}|=1$, and $|\hat{k}|=1$) and we are saying that each basis vector forms a right angle with each of the other two.

Comment: Incidentally, both the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition) of two 3D vectors and the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition) of two vectors in any vector space can be defined geometrically, without any mention of "components" or "coordinates" or "unit vectors."

Answer (score 1):

Often when we speak of the *components* of a vector, $\vec{a}$, we mean  vectors ($\vec{a_{x}}, \vec{a_{y}}, \vec{a_{z}}$, say) in particular directions  that add up vectorially to make the original vector, $\vec{a}$.

Sometimes, though, we mean ($a_{x}, a_{y}, a_{z}$): the scalar coefficients of the unit vectors in those directions. So…$$\vec{a_{x}}=a_{x}\vec{e_x}\ \ \text{etc}$$

Here's an example where we use scalar components. The cross product of two vectors is given by$$
a⃗ ×b⃗ =i⃗ (a_{y} b_{z}−a_{z} b_{y})+j⃗ (a_{z}b_{x}−a_{x} b_{z})+k⃗ (a_{x} b_{y}−a_{y} b_{x})$$

The safest thing is to follow Synge and others and to talk about either 'scalar components' or 'vector components' depending on what we mean! But most of us just refer to 'components' because it's almost always clear from the context whether we mean vector or scalar components.

You can further divide vector components into vectors in different directions, because vector components are, well, vectors.

You can't do this with scalar components, though this never causes trouble, because people revert (probably without thinking) to regarding components as vectors when they want to resolve again!

Comment: Can you show me the logic behind your saying components are scalar.

Comment: It's a matter of definition. From the way you've worded your comment, I assume that you think it's natural to regard components as vectors. That's fine. But you can write a vector as a number with unit multiplied by a unit vector: $\vec{a_{x}}=a_{x}\vec{e_x}\ \ \text{etc} $, as I wrote in my answer. Sometimes $a_{x} $, that is just the number with its unit, is called the [$x$] component.

Comment: Here's an example where we use scalar components. The cross product of two vectors is defined as $$\vec{a} \times \vec{b} =\vec{i} (a_{y} b_{z}-a_{z} b_{y}) +\vec{j} (a_{z} b_{x}-a_{x} b_{z}) + \vec{k} (a_{x} b_{y}-a_{y} b_{x})$$

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have said "defined as".

Comment: Thanks very much. There is this question bothering me:Can we divide components into further components?

Comment: See penultimate paragraph of my answer above!

Answer (score 0):

I think we **can** divide vector components into more components in a sense that, if done correctly, this is not going to violate any physics laws or lead to wrong results.

For instance, we can say that, after breaking vector components to sub-components any number of times, the vector sum of all the resulting sub-components will still be equal to the original vector.

I think we can also say that a vector could always be broken, directly (i.e., without going through Cartesian coordinates first) to any number of random components, given that all redundant components are pre-assigned some values.

For instance, in a 2d space, we can randomly choose n unit vectors (where n≥2), assign random values to all but 2 of them and then determine the component values for the remaining two.

So, if someone finds it helpful to break vector components to any number of sub-components or break a vector directly to any number of components to start with, there seems to be no cause for concern.